# Limit of a random walk

Tags: self-learning, random-walk

Suppose we have a simple random walk: $X_n\pm1$ with equal probabilities.

For any finite $n$, $E[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]=0$. Does it imply that $E[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]=0?$

Thank's!

**Edit:**

We know that $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ diverges. Formally, $\limsup\sum_{k=1}^nX_k=\infty$ and $\liminf\sum_{k=1}^nX_k=-\infty$ almost surely. So, probably this observation may help.

**Edit 2:**

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$
Following the discussion below, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }S_n$ does not exist. So, the expectation does not make sense. To put it formally, we don't have pointwise convergence because $\limsup S_n(\omega)\ne \liminf S_n(\omega)$ almost surely. Hence, $\lim S_n(\omega)$ does not exist a.s. Is it correct?

Comment: Limit? What limit?

Comment: @Did Sorry, I'm just new to TeX.

Comment: So you have $\forall n,\ u_n=0$ and you're asking about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_n$?

Comment: @anderstood No.

Comment: @anderstood Actually, I know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]=0$. And my question is whether those limits are the same?

Comment: "So, probably this observation may help." Indeed it helps to show that the formula $E[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]$ does not make sense since the limit in the expectation does not exist.

Comment: @Ariel Pretty much. It's like Grandi's series right? Based on a few convergence theorems, I don't think we can say yes:

$E[X] =  \int_{\Omega} X dP$.

So your question equals: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\Omega} X_k dP = \int_{\Omega} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k dP$ ?

You can switch sum and int if the integrand/summand is positive. So, the hypo is not satisfied.

Try Dominated Convergence Theorem:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ is not dominated by anything integrable I guess.

Try monotone convergence theorem: So close.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ converges to $\infty$, but it's not nondecreasing.

Comment: @Did Oh, you mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ does not exist. So, it's expectation does not make sense. To put it more formally, for any $\omega$, $(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k)(\omega)$ does not exit because  $(\liminf\sum_{k=1}^nX_k)(\omega)\ne (\limsup\sum_{k=1}^nX_k)(\omega)$. Am I missing something? Thank's!

Comment: @Ariel Good observation. No $\omega$ needed I think. limsup =/= liminf. So lim dne. Or if $\omega$ is needed. Maybe the requirement is that some $\omega$ makes limsup =/= liminf to say the limit does not exist?

Comment: @BCLC Of course, if $X_k\ge 0$ or $\sum E|X_k|<\infty$ it's pretty obvious that we can switch expectation and limit. And we have Fubini's theorem. However, those theorems are not "if and only if".

Comment: @Ariel Oh sorry. I meant to say that it wasn't really an answer just that those don't really satisfy the hypo of the convergence theorems so it suggests that it is not true. Ran out of space in comments. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BCLC Because of we are in the word of functions, $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are defined pointwise. So, just saying that $\liminf\ne  limsup$ implies $\lim$ does not exist is probably not correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ariel Well I suppose the limit could exist almost surely even if liminf =/= limsup. I'm not really sure. Did knows all about this stuff. Hahaha